# Webpack isn't compiling global styles

Tags: webpack

I'm working on a new webpack config for my company to get us to the latest features (Webpack 4, etc), and I'm hitting a snag. I need this webpack config to support both CSS Modules and global CSS styles, and so I've been trying to configure my loaders accordingly. What I'm finding is that my CSS/SCSS modules are being compiled, but my global styles are not.

My webpack config:

```
const cssLoader = (useModules) => {
    const base = {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            importLoaders: 5
        }
    };
    if (useModules) {
        base.options.modules = {
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__cssmod[hash:base64:5]'
        }
    }
    return base;
};

const postCssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        config: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js')
        }
    }
};

const config = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js' // TODO we want a hash here
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    cssLoader(false),
                    postCssLoader,
                    'resolve-url-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    cssLoader(false),
                    postCssLoader,
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    cssLoader(true),
                    postCssLoader,
                    'resolve-url-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    cssLoader(true),
                    postCssLoader,
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            disable: false,
            filename: 'app.css' // TODO we want a hash here
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'react-project',
            noScriptMessage: 'This requires JavaScript',
            inject: false,
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index-template.html'),
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

I don't understand what could be going wrong here.

PS. If I comment out the two rules for CSS/SCSS modules, then the global styles are bundled fine and the module ones are ignored. Maybe this means something?

Answer (score 6):

Alright, I figured it out. This was an interesting one. So, some quick background: one of the main goals of my effort is to have robust tree-shaking in our build config. In the POC I'm building, I have two projects: the "main" project, which has the webpack config, and the "child" project, which is a simple React component library.

To get tree shaking working as much as possible, I set up every configuration setting accordingly. This includes setting "sideEffects: false" in the package.json of both the parent and child projects.

That, it turns out, was my problem. This setting tells webpack that it should remove everything it possibly can while tree shaking. Webpack determines if something can be dropped if it doesn't see it being used at all in the project.

Global styles, imported as `import './styles.css'`, aren't directly linked to any of the React code that is using it. So webpack sees these styles as something it can drop, because I've already told it that there are no side effects.

To avoid this, webpack needs to believe that CSS files have side effects. To this end, a simple property can be added to the rules for global CSS files:

```
{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /\.module\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    cssLoader(false),
                    postCssLoader,
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
                sideEffects: true
            }
```